# Display some html if mysqli_fetch_assoc is empty while loop php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli, while-loop

I'm using `while loop` to fetch data from the database I want to display like nothing found the result is null or empty. I've tried using `if/else` with like: `if (empty($jobs)) echo 'nothing found';` that doesn't work. `if(!mysqli_fetch_assoc($jobs))` works but if don't show the jobs if available.

**Loop**

```
  <?php while ($job = mysqli_fetch_assoc($jobs)) { ?>
  <tr class="custom-table-body-titles">
    <td><?php echo h($job['updated_at']); ?></td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="text-dark"><?php echo h($job['title']); ?></a>
    </td>                
    <td>0/<?php echo h($job['required_freelancers']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo h($job['delivery_time']); ?> Days</td>
    <td>$<?php echo h($job['budget']); ?></td>
    <td>
      <a href="job_details.html" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Apply</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a validation to check if any results were found before even starting the loop. Assuming `$jobs` is an instance of `mysqli_result` returned by `mysqli_query()`.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($jobs) > 0)
{
    // your while loop
}
else
{
    echo "no jobs found";
}
```

Comment: This answer promotes a bad practice and better not to be upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You should keep PHP and HTML separate as much as you can.

You can fetch all results into an array before and then foreach on that array.

```
$jobs = $jobs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if($jobs) {
    foreach ($jobs as $job) {
    }
} else { 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good question which is sadly most of time is answered incorrectly.

It's a very bad practice to mix the database-related code and HTML code. There should never be a while loop like this.

Instead, the data should be fetched into array,

```
$jobs = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $jobs[] = $row;
}
```

which is then used to output the data. And once you have this array, you can use it to tell whether the query returned any data or not:

```
<?php if ($jobs) { ?>
  <?php foreach ($jobs as $job) { ?>
  <tr class="custom-table-body-titles">
    <td><?php echo h($job['updated_at']); ?></td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="text-dark"><?php echo h($job['title']); ?></a>
    </td>                
    <td>0/<?php echo h($job['required_freelancers']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo h($job['delivery_time']); ?> Days</td>
    <td>$<?php echo h($job['budget']); ?></td>
    <td>
      <a href="job_details.html" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Apply</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } else {?>
    no data
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: FYI you have used $jobs twice